# How can I get detailed geocode information?

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, geocoding, google-geocoder

```
function geocodePosition(pos) {
    geocoder.geocode({
        latLng: pos
    }, function (responses) {
        if (responses && responses.length > 0) {
            updateMarkerAddress(responses[0].formatted_address);
        } else {
            updateMarkerAddress('Cannot determine address at this location.');
        }
    });
}
```

I can get "formatted_address" using this code. How can I get the city, country and other information?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's all within the responses object that is returned from the Maps API.

Here are the properties of the response object you're using - [GeocoderResult](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#GeocoderResult)

It's easier to visualise the results by seeing the expanded JSON [on the Geocoding page](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/#JSON)

For example:

`responses[0].address_components` would get you an array of objects containing address parts.